# Multiple War Raptors on a Base

Tags: smash-up

If there are three War Raptor minions on a base, how do you count them? Would it be 15 or 9? Each has a base power of 2, and the following ability:

> Ongoing: Gains +1 power for each War Raptor on this base (including this one).

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean the "War Raptor" (The original text was "Rapture").

The War Raptor text:

> Ongoing: Gains +1 power for each War Raptor on this base (including this one).

This means, that each War Raptor gives a +1 bonus to power on each other War Raptor on the same base. The power of each War Raptor is 2 + the total number of War Raptors on the base.

- One War Raptor give 2+1 = 3 power
- Two War Raptors give 2 times (2+2) = 8 power
- Three War Raptors give 3 times (2+3) = 15 power
- Four War Raptors give 4 times (2+4) = 24 power

This is a hint that a single raptor is weak, but they become deadly while fighting in packs.

Comment: Not exactly weak; it's the deck's 2-power minion, after all!